# Updating only specific coloumn using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2, sql-update

I using struts2 as a front-end and hibernate 3.0 as ORM. I want to update customer address based on selected drop-down list. All fields are compulsory except **PIN**. If user is updating the address and leaves PIN as blank then PIN is also updated with state and so on.
I dont want to update **PIN**  if it is blank. How to achieve this, Is Hibernate having anything to update specific column something like this.

```
if(getPin()==null||getPin()=="")
{
    @update(false)  //make update false
}
```

Check snippets for getting idea about my problem.[image]

Comment: If user is updating the address and leaves PIN as blank then PIN is also updated with state and so on. I dont want to update PIN if it is blank. Those two sentences appear contradictory

Comment: @subin ,see if user is updating their address,then He have to select state,district,mandal,village,these are mandatory but Pin is optional. If user leaves Pin as blank ,suppose his previous pin=400038 in database and now he updating address ,then pin is also updated as pin=""

Comment: Ok it is clear now. You should try the @null s answer

Comment: he is telling try my answer

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you have to do is

1) load the customer
2) copy all changed fields into the still managed object, except pin when it is null

It is not sufficient to simply merge a detached entity with a null field, because hibernate can't tell whether you want to delete it or not.

Consider using a Framework like Dozer for that.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to handle a logic in setPin(String pin) method in your object.

You could do so.

```
 public void setPin(String pin){
   if(pin != null && !pin.isEmpty()){
        this.pin = pin;
     }
 }
```

Comment: my || should be &&. I changed it.

Comment: is your if statement exactly the same as my one.

Comment: Never add logic to your getters and setters, as this may harm the maintainability of your code.

Comment: Many frameworks, such as Hibernate, rely on Entities being POJOs. By adding semantics, you may loose the possibility to use those frameworks properly. In your example, you just kicked out the possibility to reset a password and, when creating a copy of an object using Dozer e.g., you loose the capability to copy empty strings. This may not sound very bad, but in a large system involving some more frameworks, promise, you'll get some really nasty bugs when adding semantics to POJOs. In theory, there's nothing wrong with adding logic to your objects, but it shouldn't be in property accessors.